# video file + fragment shader under Linux

Tags: c++, linux, shader

coming from Windows (MSVC++ 2005):
What SDK or alike do you recommend to port an C++ application (DirectShow+Direct3D) to **Linux** playing video file + using fragment shaders?

Answer (score 2):

is there any reason you need a fragment shader at all? (are you doing post processing on the video images?). You don't need to do any shader coding to get a video playing with OpenGL.

I would use ffmpeg (libavcodec actually) to do the video decoding. Displaying a frame just requires an OpenGL texture and a call to glTexSubImage2D each frame to do the update.

[Using FFMPEG in C/C++](http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use OpenGL instead.

Some tip for the implementation:
 - To achieve a good performance you
   need to make sure a good **video card
   driver** is installed.
 - If you are not familiar with OpenGL
   start it with the **'Red book'** - OpenGL
   Programming Guide
 - You may need to download the latest extension header from here 
http://www.opengl.org/registry/
 - The **library GLEW** may help you in
   identifying the    available
   extension.
 - Include the **GL/gl.h** and the **glext.h** file in your project
 - Link to the driver's opengl dynamic library: /**usr/lib64/libGL.so** or simmilar

Answer (score 1):

i would also check the gstreamer framework on linux if you need to port a more complicated directshow application. it also has some sort of graph for media playback to build. it is totally different, but if you have experience and the need for complicated directshow, then you will see some analogy.

and gstreamer also has an opengl plugin for image effects and shaders, ....

http://www.gstreamer.net/
http://www.gstreamer.net/releases/gst-plugins-gl/0.10.1.html